# on 20.04 after a recent upgrade I am unable to clear DNS cache

Tags: 20.04, dns, resolv.conf

I recently changed the NS records for a website and when I dig that using online tool such https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/ I can see that it is pointing to the correct place. and even my phone on same wifi network it goes to the correct website, but on My Ubuntu 20.04, it still goes to the previous site and not pointing to the new site correctly.

In the past I was using the following command to clear the cache, But this is not working anymore:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

I have found some similar posts and have tried many solutions which were in answers or comments but nothing has worked for me so far.

This is the response for the problem domain which I changed about 3~4 hours ago:

```
nslookup the-domain-name.org
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   the-domain-name.org
Address: xx.xx.xx.xx (INCORRECT_IP, points to the DNS provider)
Name:   the-domain-name.org
Address: xx.xx.xx.xx (I am not sure if this IP is correct or not)
```

When I look inside the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, it has the following:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                    /etc/resolv.conf                              
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search local
```

how do I solve this, and what is the correct way to flush / refresh the cache?
Someone just said point to google's DNS, how to do that ?

EDIT: Update,

I had to move another domain to new IP and same problem reoccured.
I tried everything from this article and none of it worked for me : https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-flush-dns-cache-on-linux-for.html

Summary:

dig the-domain A
<Shows Incorrect (old) IP>

dig the-domain A @8.8.8.8
<Shows the correct (new) IP>

nslookup the-domain
<Shows incorrect (old) address>

nslookup the-domain 8.8.8.8
<Shows the correct (new) address>

in any browser, chrome, Firefox, Brave, I see the old site.

Answer (score 1):

`resolvectl flush-caches`

It can depend if you are using `systemd-network` or `network-manager`.  It looks like your `resolv.conf` is pointed at `127.0.0.53`, which is a loopback address that `systemd-resolved` binds to.  It maintains its own cache and can be controlled with `resolvectl`.  Using `systemd-resolved` is the default setup in 20.04 (if using `systemd-networkd`), but not previous LTS releases.

The upstream DNS servers could also have your result cached.  If you want to query a DNS server specifically, then you can use the command `nslookup the-domain-name.org the-dns-server` or `dig the-domain-name.org @the-dns-server`.  For example, to query Google's popular quad8 server, either of those commands works.

```
nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8
dig example.com @8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I tried this before, and I tried it again now, in my case this is not working. 
Since the updated site is sitting on Netlify I am not a 100% sure what is the correct IP but in the browser I am still seeing the old site.

Comment: Some browsers have their own cache.  E.g. for *Chrome* you can flush the internal cache with the special URL `chrome://net-internals/#dns`.  You really need to know the old and new IP DNS records to understand if it is even a caching problem.  You only mention changing the `NS` records, so you may not have even changed the relevant records for the web host.  You should refer to your hosting provider's documentation or talk to their support.

Comment: Thanks @andrew-lowther. 
I will probably do this same for other domains and will see where exactly it is causing problems. as I said in the question, usually the nscd restart does the trick.